# How to tilt Google Maps in an emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, google-maps

I am using the **emulators** (AVD) by Google to run an application which contains a Google Map Activity? On a real device I can use **two fingers to tilt** the map and see 3d buildings in certain zoom levels - as shown in the screenshot.

[image: GoogleMaps screenshot]

How can I tilt the map on a **virtual device** when all have are the input devices of my computer (keyboards, mouse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Nicola's hint](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139167/16349) I [searched for *SDKController* in Google's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=SDKController&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&cells=tiles). There I found a recent (Jan 28, 2016) and [helpful comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5977#c29):

> Specifically, a pinch/rotate gesture was added in Emulator release 25.0.4 preview 5 - hold Alt to bring up the interface.

Then I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the **right** mouse button ... and it works!

[image: Tilt gesture on emulator]

Answer (score 1):

the only thing I've found on normal emulators (AVD) is to use hardware emulation:
http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

But I've never tried it. Honestly I prefer to use Genymotion devices which allows you to interact with just CTRL, ALT, SHIFT and mouse, no pain!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. However, the emulator **crashes immediately** when I **enabled port forwarding** from the device before. - [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32601901/356895).